# Get multiple sums for a vector including many factor-levels devided by NA's

Tags: r, vector, sum

Hope someone can help me with the following problem:

I have a really large vector (105264) of the following form.
A pack of values followed by a pack of NA's and then again a pack of values (and so on).

`c(123, 4525, 4365, 234, 674, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 24, 347, 457, 3246, 234, 5, 346, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, [... and so on])`

Is there any way to get me the sums for each of my pack of values seperated by my NA's? Both the values and the NA's seperate in their lenght over the vector and that's where I see the problem ...

Thanks a lot for your response!

Best regards, 
Max

Comment: Hi, did you face any issues in the below solution? It looks like you unaccepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a dummy data

```
num <- c(3, 5, 2, NA, NA, 2, 3, 7, 8, NA, 2, 3, NA, 5, 4)
```

Assuming I have understood what you want, you want the sums of `c(3, 5, 2)`, `c(2, 3, 7)` groups separated by `NA`s

We can use `tapply`

```
new <- tapply(num, cumsum(is.na(num)) , sum, na.rm = TRUE)
new

# 0  1  2  3  4 
#10  0 20  5  9
```

and then we can ignore the groups with 0 in it.

```
new[new != 0]
# 0  2  3  4 
#10 20  5  9
```

The creation of grouping variable can be seen as

```
is.na(num)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#[14] FALSE FALSE

cumsum(is.na(num))
#[1] 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm so overwhelmed about how quik I can get a helpful answer on this website! You are a great community!!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `rle` from `base R`.  Create the grouping variable with `rle` and use that to get the `sum` of non-NA adjacent elements of the original vector with `tapply`

```
grp <- with(rle(!is.na(num)), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
i1 <- !is.na(num)
tapply(num[i1], grp[i1], FUN = sum, na.rm  = TRUE)
#   1    3 
#9921 4659
```

#### data

```
num <- c(123, 4525, 4365, 234, 674, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 24, 
   347, 457, 3246, 234, 5, 346, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
```