# Get multiple/grouped sums for a vector with values separated by NA's

Tags: r, vector, sum

I have an update on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760574/get-multiple-sums-for-a-vector-including-many-factor-levels-devided-by-nas):

```
c(123, 4525, 4365, 234, 674, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  24, 347, 457, 3246, 234, 5, 346, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA) # [... and so on]
```

Is there any way to get me the sums for each of my pack of values separated by my NA's? Both the values and the NA's separate in their length over the vector and that's where I see the problem…

Ronak Shah's answer was very helpful but there remains a problem:
I have some packs of values, which equal 0 in their sum.
But this is an important information for me!
So if I use `new[new != 0]` I cut them off and I have no information on which sums belong to which pack of values in the end.

Comment: If the previous issue was resolved, but you have a new, related question, please make the new one self-contained. A link to the previous question would help, but it should be possible to answer this one even without reading the other.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just new to this website.

Comment: Here is a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760574/get-multiple-sums-for-a-vector-including-many-factor-levels-devided-by-nas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `data.table::rleid` :

```
library(data.table)
tapply(x[!is.na(x)], rleid(is.na(x))[!is.na(x)], sum)
#    1    3    5    7    9 
# 9921 4659 5289    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit convoluted. The logic is sound, but there's quite possibly a way to simplify it a bit.

```
c(123, 4525, 4365, 234, 674, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 24, 347, 457, 3246,
234, 5, 346, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 45, 778, 986, 3345, 135, NA, NA, NA, NA,
0, 0, NA, NA, 99, -2, -97, NA, NA) -> x

isna <- !is.na(x)
ix <- c(0, diff(isna)) + isna
ix[ix == 1] <- 0
ix <- cumsum(ix) + 1

ix <- ix * as.integer(isna)

sapply(split(x, ix)[-1], sum)
#    1    2    3    4    5 
# 9921 4659 5289    0    0
```

What happens is that I through various logical and arithmetic operations create an index that has a unique number corresponding to each run of non-nas. Then the vector is split along this index and each resulting element is summed.

---

Taking inspiration from Moody, here's an `rle()`-based solution

```
notnaruns <- function(x) {
    notna <- !is.na(x)
    notnarl <- rle(isna)$lengths
    repruns <- rep(1:length(notnarl), notnarl) + 1
    repruns * notna * 0.5
}

tapply(x, notnaruns(x), sum)[-1]
#    1    2    3    4    5 
# 9921 4659 5289    0    0
```

Comment: I must admit that I understand like 50% of your script. But it worked first try so thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I also made my own mix :) : `tapply( x[!is.na(x)], cumsum(diff(c(0,is.na(x)))==-1)[!is.na(x)] , sum)`

Comment: could be just `tapply( x, cumsum(diff(c(0,is.na(x)))==-1) , sum, na.rm= TRUE)` if we know for sure `x` doesn't start with `NA`

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `aggregate` and `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- is.na(x)
aggregate(cbind(val = x[!i1])~ cbind(grp = rleid(i1)[!i1]), FUN = sum)
#  grp  val
#1   1 9921
#2   3 4659
#3   5 5289
#4   7    0
#5   9    0
```